# Sort By Distance In TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting

I'm trying to sort the results of my tableView by distance closest to the user. I've separated my distance and function to populate distance to get a better hold of my data manipulation. I feel like it should be simple but, I know I'm missing it.

The distance function is this:

```
func calculateDistance(userlat: CLLocationDegrees, userLon:CLLocationDegrees, venueLat:CLLocationDegrees, venueLon:CLLocationDegrees) -> Double {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: userlat, longitude: userLon)
    let priceLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: venueLat, longitude: venueLon)
    //let distance = String(format: "%.0f", userLocation.distance(from: priceLocation)/1000)
    return userLocation.distance(from: priceLocation)/1000
}
```

PopulateData function:

```
func populateData() {
    //Pulls TableData for UITableView
    DataService.ds.REF_VENUE.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.posts = [] // THIS IS THE NEW LINE

        if snapshot.exists(){
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if let snapValue = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject],
                        let venueLat = snapValue["LATITUDE"] as? Double,
                        let venueLong = snapValue["LONGITUDE"] as? Double
                    {
                        let distance = self.calculateDistance(userlat: self.userLatt, userLon: self.userLonn, venueLat: venueLat, venueLon: venueLong)
                        if distance <= 2 {
                            let key = snap.key
                            let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: snapValue)
                            self.posts.append(post)
                        self.posts.sort(by: (posts, distance)) //Where I'm trying to sort

                        }
                    }
                }

                self.getDataForMapAnnotation()
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    })
}
```

I'm not sure if I can even sort an array of dictionaries but, the end goal is to have the tableView show the venues closest to the user. If you have any suggestions, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the distance you calculate as a property of your Post class/struct, sorting the posts array by distance would be pretty straightforward. Using [the Swift shorthand syntax for closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), your sort function could look something like this:

```
self.posts.sort {
    return $0.distance < $1.distance
}
```

This would sort the posts array by distance in ascending order.

Comment: Where would this be best utilized? Would  have to create a new function for this or would this be best implemented within one of the functions that I have already?

Comment: Where you have your current attempt at sorting would probably work. Really anywhere after you've populated the posts array and before you call `tableView.reloadData()` would be a good place to put it. I don't think you'd need to create a separate function just to sort the array.

Comment: I don't believe that I have distance as a part of my Post class structure. In my post class, I just have the metaData on the venues (ie: lat, long, name, etc) Right now, I'm trying to re-do this to make sure that it can be sorted. Everytime I try now, it tells me that distance isn't a member of posts and I'm a little confused to be honest.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant when I said "if you added the distance you calculate as a property" - you should update your Post class to include distance as a property.

Comment: I don't think I'm too sure on how to do that with the code I have set up now. That is where the problem lies. I have every class segregated so that I pass all values via arguments verses setting them up in one huge class. With that being said, if you have a different example of how would I do that, it would be very helpful.